# Practicing to learn java through the ecommerce pack app

Tags: java

Main File

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class packApp extends items {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        
        while (itemEnter.nextOrder==0) { //while loop for continuing with new order
            items.show(); // function displays and generates list and number of items
            items.showBox();// function to generate box size
            String usedBox = items.boxUse; //variable for box to be used
            String userBox = " ";//variable for box enter by user
            
            // Creating object for switch case functions
            itemEnter itemList = new itemEnter();
            
            //scanner for user to input box
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner inputBox = new Scanner(System.in); 
            
            while  (!userBox.equals(usedBox)) { //loop if user put wrong box size
                
                //assigning user input box to new variable
                String userInputBox = inputBox.nextLine();
                
                //converting user input box to upper case
                userBox = userInputBox.toUpperCase();
                
                /* if user box is correct then switch case will be 
                 * trigger depending on the number of items
                 */
                if (userBox.equals(usedBox)) { 
                     
                    switch (numberOfItem) {
                    
                    case 1:
                        itemList.itemCase1();
                        break;
                        
                    case 2:
                        itemList.itemCase2();
                        break;
                        
                    case 3:
                        itemList.itemCase3();
                        break;
                        
                    case 4:
                        itemList.itemCase4();
                        break;
                    }
                     
                 } else {
                     System.out.println("Please enter Box : " + usedBox);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Functions for creating random item numbers

```
public class items {
    static int item1, item2, item3, item4, numberOfItem;
    
     public static void itemG() {
          item1 = (int) (Math.random()*(999999 -100000 +1) +1);
          item2 = (int) (Math.random()*(999999 -100000 +1) +1);
          item3 = (int) (Math.random()*(999999 -100000 +1) +1);
          item4 = (int) (Math.random()*(999999 -100000 +1) +1);
         
          numberOfItem = (int) (Math.random()*(4-1+1)+1);
     }
      
     static String boxUse = null;
     
     public static void showBox(){
            
            int boxSize = 0; //box size 
            
            /* switch case to determine the box size 
             * according to number of items             
             */
            switch (numberOfItem) {
            case 1:
                boxSize = item1 % 10;
                break;
            
            case 2:
                boxSize = (item1 % 10) + (item2 % 10) ;
                break;
            
            case 3:
                boxSize = (item1 % 10) + (item2 % 10) + (item3 % 10);
                break;
            
            case 4:
                boxSize = (item1 % 10)+ (item2 % 10)+ (item3 % 10)+ (item4 % 10);
                break;
            }
            /********switch case for box size determination ends********************/
            
            /* Box name assignment according to size of box
             * 
             */
            if (boxSize <= 6) {
                boxUse = "A1";
                
            } else if (boxSize <= 5) {
                boxUse = "A2";
                
            } else if (boxSize <= 8) {
                boxUse = "A3";
                
            } else if (boxSize <= 14) {
                boxUse = "A4";
                
            }   else if (boxSize <= 20) {
                boxUse = "A5";
                
            }   else if (boxSize >= 20) {
                boxUse = "A6";
            }
            
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter box : "+ boxUse );
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
        }
     
     /*
      * function for item display according to number of item
      */
     public static void show() {
            //generating random items
            itemG();
            
            System.out.println("Number of items : " + numberOfItem );
                        
            switch (numberOfItem) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("1) " + item1 );
                break;
            
            case 2:
                System.out.print("1) " + item1 + " ");
                System.out.print("2) " + item2 + " ");
                break;
            
            case 3:
                System.out.print("1) " + item1 + " ");
                System.out.print("2) " + item2 + " ");
                System.out.print("3) " + item3 + " ");
                break;
            
            case 4:
                System.out.print("1) " + item1 + " ");
                System.out.print("2) " + item2 + " ");
                System.out.print("3) " + item3 + " ");
                System.out.print("4) " + item4 + " ");
                break;
            }
        }
     /* item display function ends*/
}
```

Switch cases functions to compare the user enter items and generated items

````
import java.util.Scanner;

public class itemEnter extends items {
    
    // variable for loop to get repeated order after one is finished.
    static int nextOrder = 0; 
    
    //variable for Problem message
    String problemMgs = " \nEnter 1 for missing\n      2 for damage\n      3 for oversize";
    
    //scanner to replace a box if existing box is too small or large
    Scanner newUsedBox = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    /***Function to display for problem message**/////////////
    public void missing() {
        System.out.println("Move item to problem Solve and continue to next order\n"
                + "---------------------------------");
        int nextOrder=0;
    }
    
    public void orderComplete() {
        System.out.println("Order complete! Please continue to next order");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        int nextOrder =0;
    }
    
    public void changeBox() {
        System.out.println("Enter New box:");
        items.boxUse = newUsedBox.nextLine();
        int nextOrder=1;
        System.out.println("Enter the item: "+ item1);
    }
    /**********************************************************************/
    
    /**** Switch cases functions**/
    /************************************************************ switch case 1 starts  **/
    public void itemCase1() {
        
        System.out.println("Enter the item: " +item1+ problemMgs);
        
        
        
        //initial value of user input first item
        int userItem1 =0;
        
        // loop if user input wrong item
        while (userItem1 != item1) {
            
            Scanner userItemInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            userItem1 = userItemInput.nextInt();
            
            if (userItem1== item1) {
                orderComplete();
                
            }else if (userItem1==1 || userItem1==2){
                missing();
                break;
                
            }else if (userItem1==3){
                changeBox();
            
            }else {
                System.out.println("Enter correct item :" + item1);
            }
        }
    }
    /********************************************************** switch case 1 ends  **/
    
    /********************************************************** switch case 2 starts**/
    public void itemCase2() {
        System.out.println("enter the item: " +item1+ problemMgs);
        
        Scanner userItemInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userItem2_1 =0;
        
        while (userItem2_1 != item1) {
            userItem2_1 = userItemInput.nextInt();
            if (userItem2_1== item1) {
                
                /********************item2 starts *********/
                System.out.println("enter the item: " +item2+ problemMgs);
                            
                int userItem2_2 =0;
                
                while (userItem2_2 != item2) {
                    userItem2_2 = userItemInput.nextInt();
                    if (userItem2_2== item2) {
                        orderComplete();
                        
                    }else if (userItem2_2==1 || userItem2_1==2){
                        missing();
                        break;
                        
                    }else if (userItem2_2==3){
                        changeBox();
                    
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Enter correct item :" + item2+ problemMgs);
                    }
                }
                /********************item2 ends *********/
                
            }else if (userItem2_1==1 || userItem2_1==2){
                missing();
                break;
                
            }else if (userItem2_1==3){
                changeBox();
            
            }else {
                System.out.println("Enter correct item :" + item1+ problemMgs);
            }
        }
    }
    /********************************************************** switch case 2 ends  **/
    
    /********************************************************** switch case 3 starts**/
    public void itemCase3() {
        System.out.println("enter the item: " +item1+ problemMgs);
        
        Scanner userItemInput3_1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userItem3_1 =0;
        
        while (userItem3_1 != item1) {
            userItem3_1 = userItemInput3_1.nextInt();
            
            if (userItem3_1== item1) {
                
                /********************item2 starts *********/
                System.out.println("enter the item: " +item2+ problemMgs);
                Scanner userItemInput3_2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                
                int userItem3_2 =0;
                
                while (userItem3_2 != item2) {
                    userItem3_2 = userItemInput3_2.nextInt();
                    
                    if (userItem3_2== item2) {
                        /********************item3 starts *********/
                        System.out.println("enter the item: " +item3+ problemMgs);
                        Scanner userItemInput3_3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        
                        int userItem3_3 =0;
                        
                        while (userItem3_3 != item3) {
                            
                            userItem3_3 = userItemInput3_3.nextInt();
                            if (userItem3_3== item3) {
                                orderComplete();
                                
                            }else if (userItem3_3==1 || userItem3_3==2){
                                missing();
                                break;
                                
                            }else if (userItem3_3==3){
                                changeBox();
                            
                            }else {
                                System.out.println("Enter correct item :" + item3+ problemMgs);
                            }
                        }
                        /********************item3 ends *********/
                    }else if (userItem3_2==1 || userItem3_2==2){
                        missing();
                        break;
                        
                    }else if (userItem3_2==3){
                        changeBox();
                    
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Enter correct item :" + item2+ problemMgs);
                    }
                }
                /********************item2 ends *********/
                
            }else if (userItem3_1==1 || userItem3_1==2){
                missing();
                break;
                
            }else if (userItem3_1==3){
                changeBox();
            
            }else {
                System.out.println("Enter correct item :" + item1+ problemMgs);
            }
        }
    }
    /********************************************************** switch case 3 ends  **/
    
    /********************************************************** switch case 4 starts**/
    public void itemCase4() {
        System.out.println("enter the item: " +item1+ problemMgs);
        
        Scanner userItemInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userItem4_1 =0;
        
        while (userItem4_1 != item1) {
            
            userItem4_1 = userItemInput.nextInt();
            
            if (userItem4_1== item1) {
                
                /********************item2 starts *********/
                System.out.println("enter the item: " +item2+ problemMgs);
                
                int userItem4_2 =0;
                
                while (userItem4_2 != item2) {
                    userItem4_2 = userItemInput.nextInt();
                    if (userItem4_2== item2) {
                        
                        /********************item3 starts *********/
                        System.out.println("enter the item: " +item3+ problemMgs);
                        
                        int userItem4_3 =0;
                        
                        while (userItem4_3 != item3) {
                            userItem4_3 = userItemInput.nextInt();
                            
                            if (userItem4_3== item3) {
                                
                                /********************item4 ends *********/
                                System.out.println("enter the item: " +item4+ problemMgs);
                                
                                int userItem4_4 =0;
                                
                                while (userItem4_4 != item4) {
                                    userItem4_4 = userItemInput.nextInt();
                                    if (userItem4_4== item4) {
                                        orderComplete();

                                    }else if (userItem4_4==1 || userItem4_4==2){
                                        missing();
                                        break;
                                        
                                    }else if (userItem4_4==3){
                                        changeBox();
                                    
                                    }else {
                                        System.out.println("Enter correct item :" + item3+ problemMgs);
                                    }
                                }
                                /********************item4 ends *********/

                            }else if (userItem4_3==1 || userItem4_3==2){
                                missing();
                                break;
                                
                            }else if (userItem4_3==3){
                                changeBox();
                            
                            }else {
                                System.out.println("Enter correct item :" + item3+ problemMgs);
                            }
                        }
                        /********************item3 ends *********/

                    }else if (userItem4_2==1 || userItem4_2==2){
                        missing();
                        break;
                        
                    }else if (userItem4_2==3){
                        changeBox();
                    
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Enter correct item :" + item2+ problemMgs);
                    }
                }
                /********************item2 ends *********/
                
            }else if (userItem4_1==1 || userItem4_1==2){
                missing();
                break;
                
            }else if (userItem4_1==3){
                changeBox();
            
            }else {
                System.out.println("Enter correct item :" + item1+ problemMgs);
            }
        }
    }
    /********************************************************** switch case 4 ends  **/
}

```
````

Comment: Can you explain what the code does? Also, please explore the help center for information on how to ask good questions: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Please tell in question title (and in your code, far as I am concerned): What is the purpose of the code presented?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what your program's requirements are, I can only comment on general aspects.

It looks like you're a programming beginner. Having a program do something useful is an achievement in itself, so take my comments not as criticism, but as ideas for future learning steps.

### Naming Conventions

Class names should start with uppercase.

### Object Orientation

Classes are meant as representation of things, while actions typically become methods in the classes of the things they work with. So, `itemEnter` as a class is not a good match. That sounds like an action, so it should become a method.

Inheritance typically denotes "is-a" relations. So, `class itemEnter extends items` means that `itemEnter` is a special kind of `items`. That sounds strange, and thus is a hint that the OO concept of inheritance is mis-used here.

### Class and Method Naming

Method manes should express what the method does (telling the person calling the method what to expect), and not how it is implemented internally. E.g. a method name like `itemCase1()` does not tell what it does, it justs hints at the existence of multiple versions, and that it has something to do with items.

### Arrays and Loops

You should read about arrays (or lists) and loops. You have lots of methods that just differ in the number of items they handle. Using arrays/lists and loops, the cases could all be handled in the same method. `int item1, item2, item3, item4` could become `int[] items` or `List<Integer> items`.

### Parameter Passing

All your methods are no-args ones. Whenever you need information created in one method to be used in another one, you use (static) fields. Try to restructure your code so that methods get their input data as method parameters and deliver their results as method return values.

### Separation of Computation and User Interface

Computation and user interface should be clearly separated, ideally being in different classes. E.g. in `showBox()` you intermix both, the box size computation, and the presentation to the user.

### Recommendations

As this is a learning exercise, I'd invite you to start anew with a different approach, driven by a domain analysis:

- What are the things that I deal with? E.g. Items and Boxes. They should become classes.
- What properties do they have? E.g. item and box sizes. These should become (non-static) fields in these classes?
- What are the questions your program should be able to answer? These should become methods. E.g.

  - Does a given set of items fit into a box?
  - Which is the smallest box that a given set of items can be packed into?
  - Into a partially-filled box, can this addional item be added?
- What are the commands that a user wants to do with your program? They should end up as methods in a user interface class, with a main method that repeatedly reads a command, executes the requested method, and presents the results. Commands could e.g. be:
- Add an item to the "cart".
- Have the cart items packed into a best-fit box.

With this approach, your new program will most likely look very different from the current one.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense for any of your classes to extend `items` (which should be capitalised as `Items`).

You're over-using statics, and not properly encapsulating your items into a class.

`main` needs to be separated out into subroutines.

You have a habit of writing `while` on a condition that hasn't had a chance to be set. This doesn't make much sense; either `do / while` with the predicate at the end, or `while (true)` with a `break` in the middle.

`itemEnter` doesn't deserve to be a class at all; it doesn't meaningfully capture any state or encapsulate any operations that shouldn't just be in the main console-interface class.

There's a reason there was a warning about a resource that you needed to suppress: that `Scanner` shouldn't be initialised in a loop, and instead should only be initialised once, probably as a member variable on the application.

I really don't understand  `while (!userBox.equals(usedBox))`. To me it seems like you're printing a prompt, and only continuing if the user re-enters the box name from that prompt back to you. Why do this at all?

Your case 1/2/3/4 logic is convoluted and needs to be replaced with loops.

Don't generate four random numbers as hard-coded variables - instead, loop or stream.

Don't call `Math.random()`; the actual `Random` class has more appropriate integer methods.

Your box check runs through every single box option which is O(n) time. As a matter of learning, you should use `binarySearch` instead, which has better time complexity (though won't make much of a difference here since the list of box sizes is so small).

### Suggested

The following is not strictly equivalent, but is in the ballpark.

**PackApp.java**

```
package com.stackexchange.ecommerce;

import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class PackApp {
    private final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        new PackApp().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        boolean nextOrder;

        do {
            nextOrder = false;
            Items items = new Items();

            out.printf("Number of items: %d%n", items.getItems().size());
            out.println(items.description());

            out.printf(
                  "%nEnter box: %s"
                + "%n---------------------------"
                + "%n",
                items.boxName);

            for (int item: items.getItems())
                nextOrder |= processItem(items, item);

            orderComplete();
        } while (nextOrder);
    }

    private boolean processItem(Items items, int item)
    {
        while (true) {
            out.printf(
                "enter the item %d"
                + "%nEnter 1 for missing"
                + "%n      2 for damage"
                + "%n      3 for oversize"
                + "%n      4 for OK"
                + "%n",
                item
            );
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1, 2 -> {
                    missing();
                    return false;
                }
                case 3 -> {
                    changeBox(items);
                    return true;
                }
                case 4 -> { return false; }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void missing() {
        out.println("Move item to problem Solve and continue to next order");
        out.println("---------------------------------");
    }

    public void changeBox(Items items) {
        out.println("Enter New box:");
        items.boxName = input.nextLine();
    }

    private static void orderComplete() {
        out.println("Order complete! Please continue to next order");
        out.println("-------------------------------");
    }
}
```

**Items.java**

```
package com.stackexchange.ecommerce;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Items {
    private static final Random rand = new Random();
    private static final int[] boxIndices = {5, 6, 8, 14, 20};
    private static final String[] boxNames = {"A2", "A1", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6"};

    public String boxName;
    private final int[] items;

    private static int randomItem(int index) {
        return rand.nextInt(100_000, 1_000_000);
    }

    public Items() {
        int numberOfItem = rand.nextInt(1, 5);
        items = IntStream.range(0, numberOfItem)
                .map(Items::randomItem)
                .toArray();

        boxName = makeBoxName();
    }

    public int boxSize() {
        return Arrays.stream(items)
                .map(i -> i % 10)
                .sum();
    }

    private String makeBoxName() {
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(boxIndices, boxSize());
        if (index < -1)
            index = -index - 1;
        else if (index == -1)
            index = 0;
        return boxNames[index];
    }

    private String formatItem(int index) {
        return String.format(
            "%d) %d%n",
            index + 1, items[index]
        );
    }

    public String description() {
        return IntStream.range(0, items.length)
            .mapToObj(this::formatItem)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    public List<Integer> getItems() {
        return Arrays.stream(items)
                .boxed().toList();
    }
}
```